# How To Get Username from PHP Header

Tags: php

I can’t figure out how to obtain a user's `$username` from the php header.

After signing in/signing up, the header contains a variable with the user's username, but I can't figure out how to get that variable back when I want to use it for the profile.php page. Everyone's suggested using `$_GET['username']`, but for some reason that doesn’t seem to be working. I'm sure it’s obvious, I just can’t figure it out.

Here's my header:

```
header('location: home.php?user='.$username);
```

I just want to be able to get that `$username` variable for my `profile.php` file so I can echo that username.

*UPDATE* Retried it based on suggestions, profile php looks as follows:

```
    <?php if(isset($_GET['user']))  {

    echo $username;

} else {

    echo "Error";
} ?>
```

still manages to produce an error

Comment: The correct answer is: `$_GET['user']`

Comment: `if(isset($_GET['user'])){...}`

Answer (score 1):

If your header is:

```
header('location: home.php?user='.$username);
```

Use this to get username:

```
$user = $_GET['user'];
```

`$_GET` array contain parameters from query string. Query string looks like:

```
param1=foo&param2=bar // etc
```

So when you want to get parameter from the query string use `$_GET['param1']`, `$_GET['param2']` etc.

### Update, because of comments

Your code is a bit wrong:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['user']))  {

    echo $username;

} else {

    echo "Error";
} ?>
```

Firstly, you check if `$_GET['user']` is assigned. If yes, you do `echo $username;`. `$username` var is undefined — you didn't assign anything to this variable.

You have to use:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['user']))  {
    echo $_GET['user'];
} else {
    echo "Error";
} ?>
```

Or this:

```
$username = $_GET['user'];
<?php if(isset($username))  {
    echo $username;
} else {
    echo "Error";
} ?>
```

Comment: @JakeGould true, but I am writing answers depending on what user asked and depending on tags.

Comment: Yes. I have tried this many times only to be left with a 'username' is undefined error

Comment: @user3630206 check network tab in your browser console. Also, do `var_dump($username)`. What is contents? Are you sure you send correct username?

Comment: $_POST **doesn't** use the query string. $_REQUEST may include items from the query string dependig on the configuration of PHP.

Comment: @user3630206 don't paste code here. update answer with it

Comment: @user3630206 I said, that you should do `var_dump($username);` in file, where you use `header()` function

Comment: unfortunately can't answer my own questions until 8 more hrs

Comment: @user3630206 you don't need to answer your own question. Edit your answer and add code to it.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav If the OP has an answer he **should** answer it and mark it accepted. Editing code into the question leaves the question apparently unanswered.

Comment: @MikeW he didn't solved the problem, he still has some problems, read prev comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your updated code is still wrong since you're checking the existence of $_GET['user']` but echoing an apparently uninitialised variable.

Try this:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['user']))  {
  echo $_GET['user'];
} else {
  echo "Error";
} ?>
```